# How to solve jQuery UI and TableGear conflict?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, conflict

I'm using [Tablegear](http://andrewplummer.com/code/tablegear/) and jQuery UI's date picker in my site and somehow only the one I declare first is working. I'm not sure but it can be a conflict issue, can't be?

Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/nc3Rs/

Notice that I added the `TableGears1.6-jQuery.js` as a resource. As soon as I remove this resource the date picker begins to work.

How can I solve this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at this and found that if you remove the bit of script shown below from the end of the `TableGears1.6-jQuery.js` file, the datepicker script will start working again:

```
// Fix for jQuery 1.4.2 strangely not firing browser native focus event.
jQuery.fn.focus = function(){
  this.each(function(){
    if(this.focus) this.focus();
  });
};
```

Comment: Wow! How did you find out? Do you have an idea about why they wrote this bit of script?

Comment: It was the only thing in the source that looked like it might cause trouble. And I have no idea why it was added, but I am glad it solved your problem :) Also, I added this problem to the TableGears github issue list: http://github.com/andrewplummer/TableGear/issues/#issue/1